# The internet address is not valid in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

When i am trying to open excel file from SharePoint 2007 library it saying

> The internet address is not valid.

Please help me.

Comment: Does the name of the excel file include special characters like "+" ??

Comment: Is this behavior for all users? Is this behavior happening to all files?

Comment: @Jinxed no there is no special characters and it was working before.

Comment: @AmalHashim yes it's for all user and it seems to be happening for all other sharepoint sites.

Comment: Make sure ISA is not blocking SharePoint URL

Comment: May i know how can i check ISA blocking or not but all the folder libraries are accessing fine there is issue only with files and images.

Comment: I found this thread https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/b314cf5f-844c-412e-ae94-926ee56f043f/sharepoint-document-trouble-web-server-busyinternet-address-not-valid?forum=sharepointadminlegacy

Comment: @AmalHashim, could please get me out of from this issue, i am not able to replicate the issue.

Comment: Is it the same for all other excel files? or is it just for this particular file?

Comment: It's for all files.